# How to detect jQuery selector inside the function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm initilizing `select2.js` library on two `select` element as follow:

```
$("#zones-list, #zones-list-popup").select2({
    placeholder: "Select Your City",
    dropdownParent: $(".modal-content"),   // this line should only be for #zones-list-popup"
    ajax: {
       url: ...
```

As I've commented in the code above, I need to have this parameter `dropdownParent: $(".modal-content")` only for `#zones-list-popup` selector. Any idea how can I do a conditional thing inside a jquery function that has multiple selector?

Comment: Do you mean `$("#zones-list-popup .modal-content")`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon No .. I need to init it for two different element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, per se. Call `select2` twice instead.

```js
const options = {/*etc*/};
$("#zones-list").select2(options);
$("#zones-list-popup").select2({...options, dropdownParent: $(".modal-content")});
```